# Simplify a method with LINQ to update a series of nested property values

Tags: c#, linq

Can this be simplified?

```
public int ReplaceNameInHistoryForPublisher(string OldName, string NewName)
{
    int iSize = _DutyAssignments.Count;
    int iTotalReplaced = 0, iTotal = 0;

    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < iSize; i++)
        {
            DutyAssignmentEntry oEntry = _DutyAssignments[i];

            int iSizeAssign = oEntry.Assignments.Count;
            for(int iAssign = 0; iAssign < iSizeAssign; iAssign++)
            {
                if(oEntry.Assignments[iAssign].Name == OldName)
                {
                    oEntry.Assignments[iAssign].Name = NewName;
                    iTotal++;
                }
            }

            if(iTotal > 0)
            {
                _DutyAssignments[i] = oEntry;
                iTotalReplaced += iTotal;
            }
        }

        return iTotalReplaced;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        SimpleLog.Log(ex);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I have a `List` of `DutyAssignmentEntry` objects. Each of these objects has an `Assignments` property. As expected, that variable is a `List` of `Assignment` objects.

The `Assignment` object has a `Name` property which is what i am looking at to update.

My code works but I wondering if it can be improved with LINQ?

Comment: If you want to update something, don't ask for LINQ. That is a tool to query something. The tool to update it is a loop.

Comment: If you want to know if something can be improved you also need to say what you want improved? Do you think your current code is not readable enough? Do you think it is too slow (if so have you actually done performance testing)? Do you think it might have bugs? "improved" is a very subjective concept...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can simplify it:

```
public int ReplaceNameInHistoryForPublisher(string OldName, string NewName)
{
    var assignmentsToUpdate = _DutyAssignments
        .SelectMany(da => da.Assignments.Where(a => a.Name == OldName))
        .ToList();

    assignmentsToUpdate.ForEach(x => x.Name = NewName);

    return assignmentsToUpdate.Count;
}
```

But note that LINQ is not the right tool to update a collection but to query it. You can use it to find out what you have to update. I hide the loops in the LINQ query and in `List<T>.ForEach`.

Btw, `Assignment` is a reference type, so you can simply change the `Name` property, you don't need to overwrite this reference in the list with itself(`_DutyAssignments[i] = oEntry`).